# Skip Reading an XML Element in a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: xml, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2016 that reads a XML file. What I would like to do is to skip saving an element if there is no value.

The XML element should look like something like this

```
<PROJECT_TERMSX>
      <TERM>Extramural Activities</TERM>
      <TERM>programs</TERM>
      <TERM>research facility</TERM>
</PROJECT_TERMSX>
```

but many of the elements are formed like

```
<PROJECT_TERMS xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
```

My code to insert the data into a table is

```
INSERT into ADMIN_ExPORTER_TERMS (APPLICATION_ID, TERM)
    SELECT
        APPLICATION_ID,
        nref.value('.','varchar(max)') TERM                     
    FROM 
        [ADMIN_Exporter_Files_XML] 
    CROSS APPLY
        XMLData.nodes('//PROJECT_TERMSX/TERM') AS R(nref)
    WHERE
        APPLICATION_ID = @APPLICATION_ID
```

I would like to skip the elements that has the http Schema but don't know how to structure the code. I have no control over the original XML structure.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. The *XPath* expression `.nodes('/PROJECT_TERMSX/TERM')` will filter out not needed XML with NULL values.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, APPLICATION_ID INT, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (APPLICATION_ID, xmldata)
VALUES (10, N'<PROJECT_TERMSX>
      <TERM>Extramural Activities</TERM>
      <TERM>programs</TERM>
      <TERM>research facility</TERM>
</PROJECT_TERMSX>')
, (10, N'<PROJECT_TERMSX xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @APPLICATION_ID INT = 10;

--INSERT into ADMIN_ExPORTER_TERMS (APPLICATION_ID, TERM)
SELECT APPLICATION_ID
    , col.value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') AS TERM                     
FROM @tbl AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY tbl.XMLData.nodes('/PROJECT_TERMSX/TERM') AS tab(col)
WHERE APPLICATION_ID = @APPLICATION_ID;
```

> Output

```
+----------------+-----------------------+
| APPLICATION_ID |         TERM          |
+----------------+-----------------------+
|             10 | Extramural Activities |
|             10 | programs              |
|             10 | research facility     |
+----------------+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes standardization can help you a lot, even though more steps are needed. In my case, I used the following table valued-function (see below) to convert **ANY XML** file to a SQL Table table and from there I can do whatever I want.  The good thing is that I don't need to code for each xml change, it is dynamically converted and I can manage the data as a regular table.

USE:

```
select *  from Utility.FlattenXml('<a>1</a><b></b><c>3</c>')
```

PROCEDURE:

```
USE [YOUR_DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [Utility].[FlattenXml](@xmlDoc XML)  
RETURNS TABLE 
AS RETURN 
WITH CTE AS ( 

    SELECT 
            1 AS lvl,  
            x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Name,  
            CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS ParentName, 
            CAST(1 AS INT) AS ParentPosition, 
            CAST(N'Element' AS NVARCHAR(20)) AS NodeType,  
            x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS FullPath,  
            x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')  
            + N'[' 
            + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NVARCHAR)  
            + N']' AS XPath,  
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Position, 
            x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Tree,  
            x.value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Value,  
            x.query('.') AS this,         
            x.query('*') AS t,  
            CAST(CAST(1 AS VARBINARY(4)) AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS Sort,  
            CAST(1 AS INT) AS ID  
    FROM @xmlDoc.nodes('/*') a(x)  
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
            p.lvl + 1 AS lvl,  
            c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Name,  
            CAST(p.Name AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS ParentName, 
            CAST(p.Position AS INT) AS ParentPosition, 
            CAST(N'Element' AS NVARCHAR(20)) AS NodeType,  
            CAST(p.FullPath + N'/' + c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS FullPath,  
            CAST(p.XPath + N'/'+ c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')+ N'['+ CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
            ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NVARCHAR)+ N']' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS XPath,  
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
            ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Position, 
            CAST( SPACE(2 * p.lvl - 1) + N'|' + REPLICATE(N'-', 1) + c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Tree,  
            CAST( c.value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) AS Value, c.query('.') AS this,  
            c.query('*') AS t,  
            CAST(p.Sort + CAST( (lvl + 1) * 1024 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) * 2) AS VARBINARY(4)) AS VARBINARY(MAX) ) AS Sort,  
            CAST((lvl + 1) * 1024 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) * 2) AS INT)

    FROM CTE p  
    CROSS APPLY p.t.nodes('*') b(c)), cte2 AS (  
                                                SELECT 
                                                lvl AS Depth,  
                                                Name AS NodeName,  
                                                ParentName, 
                                                ParentPosition, 
                                                NodeType,  
                                                FullPath,  
                                                XPath,  
                                                Position, 
                                                Tree AS TreeView,  
                                                Value,  
                                                this AS XMLData,  
                                                Sort, 
                                                ID
                                                FROM cte  
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
            p.lvl,  
            x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
            p.Name, 
            p.Position, 
            CAST(N'Attribute' AS NVARCHAR(20)),  
            p.FullPath + N'/@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
            p.XPath + N'/@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
            1, 
            SPACE(2 * p.lvl - 1) + N'|' + REPLICATE('-', 1)  
            + N'@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
            x.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
            NULL,  
            p.Sort,  
            p.ID + 1  
    FROM CTE p  
    CROSS APPLY this.nodes('/*/@*') a(x)  
    )  

    SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Sort, ID) AS ID,  
            ParentName, ParentPosition,Depth, NodeName, Position,   
            NodeType, FullPath, XPath, TreeView, Value, XMLData 
    FROM CTE2
```

Hope this help!